# If $X$ is a random variable such that $a<X<b$, is the expected value between those values as well?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Assuming $a$ and $b$ are real values. I saw this in the Spanish Wikipedia page about expected value but I don't know if this is true, I'm using high school math.

Comment: It is true.  Are you interested in discrete or continuous random variables?

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm interested in discrete random variables since I'm not using integrals, therefore I can't calculate continuous ones.

Comment: And what's your preferred definition of expected value?

Comment: @NateEldredge The books that I'm using define it as $E[X]=x_1*p_1+x_2*p_2+...+x_n*p_n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is a discrete random variable which takes the values $x_1, \dots, x_n$ with probabilities $p_1, \dots, p_n$.  If $X > a$ then every one of the $x_i$ must be greater than $a$, so the expected value of $X$ is
$$E[X] = x_1 p_1 + \dots + x_n p_n > a p_1 + \dots + a p_n = a(p_1 + \dots + p_n) = a \cdot 1.$$
The argument when $X < b$ is similar.